# EF 4.2 Many to many bug?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many

We are using the ASP.NET membership to manager our user and I found a problem using Entity Framework 4.2

I have the table in db called Aspnet_Users and I Created My class as:

```
public class Aspnet_User
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public Guid ApplicationID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string LoweredUserName { get; set; }
    public string MobileAlias { get; set; }
    public bool IsAnonymous { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastActivityDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Aspnet_Membership Aspnet_Membership { get; set; }
    public virtual Aspnet_Profile Aspnet_Profile { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Aspnet_Role> Aspnet_Roles { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Agent> Agents { get; set; }
}
```

My Entity Configuration:

```
public class Aspnet_UserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Aspnet_User>
{
    public Aspnet_UserConfiguration()
        : base()
    {
        HasKey(p => p.ID);

        Property(p => p.ID).HasColumnName("UserId").IsRequired();

        Property(p => p.MobileAlias).IsOptional();

        HasOptional(p => p.Aspnet_Profile).WithRequired();
        HasOptional(p => p.Aspnet_Membership).WithRequired();

        HasMany(p => p.Aspnet_Roles).WithMany(a => a.Aspnet_Users).Map(mc =>
            {
                mc.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                mc.MapRightKey("RoleId");
                ToTable("aspnet_UsersInRoles");
            });

        HasMany(p => p.Agents).WithMany(a => a.Aspnet_Users).Map(mc =>
            {
                mc.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                mc.MapRightKey("AgentId");
                ToTable("aspnet_UsersAgent");
            });

        ToTable("aspnet_Users");
    }
```

And Finally my Agent table:

```
public class Agent
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string ShortBio { get; set; }
    public string ExtendedBio { get; set; }
    public string Tel { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string ImageURL { get; set; }
    public string BranchName { get; set; }
    public string UserPassword { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastLogin { get; set; }
    public bool? Active { get; set; }
    public bool ShowMap { get; set; }
    public string BatchNoPrefix { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, Surname); }
    }

    public virtual AgentsAddress Address { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PaymentNotification> PaymentNotifications { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Authority> Authorities { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Aspnet_Users> Aspnet_Users { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is: When I try to select my Aspnet_User in the class Agent, I'm getting a error:

```
Invalid object name 'dbo.Aspnet_UserAgent'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.Aspnet_UserAgent'.
```

I figured out that this error occur because my classname is in singular: Aspnet_User instead of Aspnet_Users.

But if I created the relationship inside my Configuration(see class aspnet_UserConfiguration), the system should not try to get aspnet_UsersAgent? Why is it try to get dbo.ClassName1_ClassName2? Is It a bug?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: But the system tries to get `Aspnet_UserAgent` as the exception says and not `aspnet_UsersAgent` as you say. You also have a collection of `Aspnet_Users` in your `Agent` class. But your class name is `Aspnet_User`. Your code wouldn't compile. Can you check the singulars and plurals in your code snippets carefully and also small and capital letters? It's a bit confusing.

Comment: @Slauma But I try to say that the table is: Aspnet_UsersAgent with this code: `ToTable("aspnet_UsersAgent");` The system should try to get `Aspnet_UsersAgent` not `Aspnet_UserAgent`
And I have another problem: The Membership creates a table called **aspnet_UsersInRoles** and When I try to add a row in this table, I receive a similar error:
**Invalid object name 'dbo.Aspnet_UsersAspnet_Roles'.**

Comment: Clarifying my problem: My mapping is not working when I try to add a new row to a table.

Comment: Did you add `Aspnet_UserConfiguration` to the `modelbuilder` configurations in your derived `DbContext`?

Comment: Yes. I found my problem! When I create the Map, I forgot to put `mc.ToTable("aspnet_UsersInRoles")`. If you look above, you will se I wrote only `ToTable("aspnet_UsersInRoles")`.
I made a simple mistake and received error in execution time only. I will delete this question.

Comment: Thank you for yous attention @slauma.

Comment: Aaaahhhh, I see - now! Congrats!